# element tree parse xml text string to be called by eval

Tags: python, xml, string, eval

I use eval('string') in a python script to execute a piece of java scrit, and I would like to store the string in a xml and then parse use element tree as text string, the problem is in this way, the eval() will return nothing since the parsed string is a string object not a original string which can be reconigized by eval(), anybody knows how to solve this problem? I am a freshman on programming, any suggestions will be highly appriciated.

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't use eval... But to answer your question on how to store an object to be later executed but eval, you do `repr(my_object)`, this will often return a string, suitable for eval, but **this is not always true**.